# Getting the value from a radio button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form with radio inputs and want to use javascript to analyse the results.
I am getting stuck at retrieving the form information in my JavaScript function:

```
function getResults(formInput){
    alert (formInput.question1);
}
```

Where question1 is the "name" of my radio button group.

This returns "object Nodelist" and I haven't a clue what's wrong, I would expect it to return "1", which is the value of my radio button when selected.

I don't want to work out which radio button is selected and which isn't, I need to know the value associated with the selected radio button.

Comment: Have you checked the code repository at javascript.internet.com? You've got to write a loop and check each of the buttons for the selected value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `object Nodelist` that you're referring to is being returned because you have a group of elements that share the same name. If you want to see the value of the radio button that's checked, you need to loop through the collection:

```
function getResults() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("question1");

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            alert(radios[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zJR7M/4/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice on my previous post and the response here, I shall try it and see what I can make

Comment: @JosephRobins, please see updated post. There was a bug in my previous answer.

Comment: Oh you beauty!  I am so happy now :):):)  Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can get a more simple and elegant solution:

```
<input type=radio name=my_radio value=value_1>

var my_form = document.querySelector('#my_form');
var my_radio = my_form.elements.my_radio;

alert(my_radio.value)  // this is the radionodelist.value you can check it on mdn
```